# Waiting Until Dispatch Queue has Completed - Timing - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

Say I have an app with the following method strucutre :

```
[self method1];
[self method2];
```

And that method 1 contains a dispatch queue such as :

```
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    switch (exportSession.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:{
            NSLog (@"FAIL");
            break;
        }
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted: {
            NSLog (@"SUCCESS");
}
};
 }];
```

I want to only proceed to execute [method2] once the dispatch queue in method1 has completed. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the call to `-method2` inside the completion handler block.

Comment: Good answer so long as it doesn't matter if method2 does not happen on the main thread.

Comment: And if it does, just put the dispatching of it to the main queue inside the completion block.